# SSD Partition Corrupted

Tags: ssd, partition, recovery

I recently installed a dual-drive setup where I have an SSD and an HDD. I had installed the OS and Apps on the SSD, and other stuff stayed on HDD. Recently my battery died, and I have been using the laptop on power (taken the battery off) because of which it would experience sudden shut down (due to frequent power failure in my area)

Yesterday when I started the Mac, it loaded up a grey boot screen with a loading bar. The loading bar took about 10-15 minutes to complete and then the Mac shut down again. I restarted and same thing happened.

I then booted in Recovery Mode, and found out that the SSD Disk is showing up fine (Verified). However, the partition on it is greyed out and the Disk Utility can't seem to repair it.

I want to know what I should do now (will most likely re-install OS X), and if the problem is with the SSD or is it just that something went corrupt (at the OS level) on the partition?

OS X Mountain Lion, SSD: 128 GB Samsung Evo, MacBook Pro 13" Early 2011 Model

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a reinstall to me.

Every time you get a power-cut or you have to force-shut the power on the computer, you should run Repair Disk in the Disk Manager afterwards, because the HFS+ filesystem really is not very robust. Leave it for too long, with too many power cuts, and you could end up with an un-repairable partition.

So I sincerely hope that you had a backup, and it looks like you get to go through the OS X install procedure.

Oh - and go out and buy a replacement battery! It will be worth it in the long run, if only for providing enough power to allow you to shut down the machine properly in case of an extended power outage.

Comment: So the issue is with just the partition, and the SSD is not an issue right?

Comment: I would not assume there was a hardware failure yet. First, you need to stop the system from having the plug pulled from under it, and then if it remains stable you know it was just a partition problem. HFS+ is notoriously crappy, and pulling the plug from under it is a good way to corrupt a partition

Comment: Journalled HFS should be OK with power cuts - one of the main reasons journalling was added

Comment: It should be, but demonstrably isn't in HFS's case. It's so easily corrupted that it's way past time it was dropped in favour of a better file system.

Answer (score 1):

Frequent power outs could lead to problems since your system does not have  batery to save the memory.

Running without battery will cut down the CPU speed to 1/2 of the normal.

The disk partition showing in gray, but the Disk Utility does not report an Error!

Could be you are looking at one of the 2 hidden partitions? one is EFI the other one is the OS X recovery.

Reset your SMC and your EFI.

If that fails, run the fsck-fy to attempt to repair.